# Reason for $F_s = kx$ in MIT video lecture #1 by Instructor J.Kim Vandiver on engineering dynamics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring

In the [Video Lecture #1](https://youtu.be/GUvoVvXwoOQ?t=1286), Instructor J. Kim Vandiver says at 21:26:

> ".. And so third, you deduce the signs basically from the direction of the arrows. First we need what's called your constitutive relationship. So the spring force, fs, well you've made x positive so it keeps things nice, the spring constant's a positive
>   number, so fs is kx. Fd is bx dot..."

Question: I did not follow the argument why Fs = kx? Fs is supposed to be in the direction opposite to the direction of motion (motion is downward for +ve x in the chosen coordinate, so Fs is upward, hence negative)?

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you add a link? That course is on OCW, right?

Answer (score 1):

Vandiver is using a fairly unusual convention.  The minus signs that appear are relative to the arrows drawn on the diagram he drew, rather than to a global coordinate system.

That is, $F_s>0$ means that the force $F_s$ is in the direction of the $F_s$-arrow on the diagram (which is pointed up).  $x>0$ means that the displacement $x$ is in the direction of the $x$-arrow on the diagram (which is pointed down).

It is not the typical way to do things, but it does work out in the end.